# Find out if a user is logged into wordpress from id

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am looking for a function to check if a user is logged into wordpress via their id.

i am aware of this function.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}
```

but i was wondering if their is a function that does it via id so it would be like the following below.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in(1) ) {
    echo 'this user is logged in';
}
```

cant find one anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can go around it like:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
     $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     if ( 1 == $current_user->ID ) {
      // do stuff.
     } else {
       // do stuff.
     }
 }
```